# Вывод даты на экран, которая не зависит от формата записи даты в БД

Tags: c#, .net, дата, datetime

Имеется кусок исходного код на C#:

```
var message = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.YYYY}",
_beginDate.ToShortDateString());
```

в данном случае, _beginDate переменная типа DateTime, которая получает значение из БД Oracle. Но данный тип вывода имеет недостаток, вывод даты на экран полностью зависит от того, как записана дата в БД, например dd/MM/YYYY, либо dd Month YYYY и тд. Например может вывести сообщение: "22 января 2018" или "22/01/2018". т.е. полностью зависит от параметра в БД NLS_FORMAT.
Необходимо как то убрать эту зависимость, чтоб всегда выводило как "dd.MM.YYYY".

Была сделана попытка убрать данную зависимость, а именно:

```
var message = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", _beginDate.Day.ToString(), _beginDate.Month.ToString(), _beginDate.Year.ToString();
```

Почти удалось, но месяц выводится без нуля,
например "22.1.2018" вместо "22.01.2018"

Answer (score 2):

Уберите `ToShortDateString` и замените `YYYY` на [`yyyy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
 var message = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", _beginDate);
```

Иначе получается, что Вы преобразовываете дату в строку, а затем строку пытаетесь форматировать как дату.

> вывод даты на экран полностью зависит от того, как записана дата в БД,

В оригинальном коде дата преобразовывается в строку через [`ToShortDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx). Возвращаемое значение этого метода зависит от текущих настроек локализации/выбранной культуры .Net и не должно быть связано с настройками NLS БД.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй преобразовать полученную из БД дату не в String, а в DateTime..

Comment: она и так в формате DateTime

Comment: Так перед форматировнием не переводи в String